# Using a Hash Array to statistically analyze Romeo and Juliet text. I am off by 2 words out of 3684

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

So the number of unique words used in Romeo and Juliet is supposed to be 3648. I am getting 3682. I have debugged and rewrote the update function as much as I could. The teacher and other students in the class are also getting 3648. So basically I'm off by 2.

The problem is in the update function which inputs a key into the hash array, checking for collision and such. It updates the size whenever there is a new entry.

Here is my code pasted in hastebin: http://hastebin.com/irawafeyen.avrasm

Here is the text of Romeo and Juliet pasted in hastebin: http://hastebin.com/semuponata.hs

In order for my code to run, you must save the file as RomeoAndJuliet.txt in the same folder as the code

And here is my code pasted for your convenience here.

```
    #define HASHSIZE 4001
    #define ARRAY_SIZE 23868
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    // Use folding on a string, summed 4 bytes at a time
    int sfold(const char* key) 
    {
        unsigned int *lkey = (unsigned int *)key;
        int intlength = strlen(key)/4;
        unsigned int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<intlength; i++)
            sum += lkey[i];
    // Now deal with the extra chars at the end
        int extra = strlen(key) - intlength*4;
        char temp[4];
        lkey = (unsigned int *)temp;
        lkey[0] = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<extra; i++)
            temp[i] = key[intlength*4+i];
        sum += lkey[0];
        return sum % HASHSIZE;
    }

    class HashArray
    {

        struct Node
        {
            string word;// = "null";
            int frequency;
        };

        private:
            int size;


        public:
            Node hasharr[HASHSIZE];

            HashArray()
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < HASHSIZE; i++)
                    hasharr[i].frequency = 0;   
                size = 0;
            }
            ~HashArray() {} 

            void update(string charkey)
            {
                const char* temp = charkey.c_str();
                int intkey = sfold(temp);       
                if (hasharr[intkey].frequency == 0)
                    {
                        hasharr[intkey].word = charkey;
                        hasharr[intkey].frequency = 1;
                        size++;
                    }
                else if(hasharr[intkey].word == charkey)
                        hasharr[intkey].frequency++;
                else 
                    {
                        while(hasharr[intkey].frequency != 0 && hasharr[intkey].word != charkey)
                        {
                            if(intkey > 4000) 
                                intkey = 1;
                            intkey++;
                        }

                        if(hasharr[intkey].word == charkey)
                            hasharr[intkey].frequency++;
                        else 
                        {
                        hasharr[intkey].word = charkey;
                        hasharr[intkey].frequency++;    
                        size++;             
                        }
                    }
            }
            void hashsize()
            {
                cout <<"The amount of entries in the hash table is "<< size;
            }

            void find1timewords() // prints all words that appear only one and then prints the amount of these types of words.
            {
                int i = 0;
                int count = 0;
                while(i < 4000) 
                {
                    if(hasharr[i].frequency == 1)
                    {
                        cout << endl << i << " ";
                        cout << hasharr[i].frequency <<" "<< hasharr[i].word<<" ";
                        count++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                cout << " number of words appearing one time: " << count;
            }

            void printFirstN(int n) // Prints the first N hash entries at indexes 0 thru N.
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    cout << endl << "tag: " << i << " word: " << hasharr[i].word << " frequency: " << hasharr[i].frequency <<endl;
            }

            void printTopN(int n) //print the first N most used words.
            {
                int max;
            }
    };



    int main()
    {
        HashArray hasharray;

        ifstream inputFile;
        inputFile.open("RomeoAndJuliet.txt");

        string temp;

        while(inputFile >> temp)
            hasharray.update(temp);

        hasharray.hashsize();
        //hasharray.printFirstN(25);
        //hasharray.find1timewords();


        inputFile.close();
        cin.get();
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean 3684, not 3648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for hash collision checking goes past the end of your hash array.
This code

```
while(hasharr[intkey].frequency != 0 && hasharr[intkey].word != charkey)
{
    if(intkey > 4000) 
        intkey = 1;
    intkey++;
}
```

has a problem when `intkey` is exactly 4000. The value of `intkey` when it loops will be 4001 due to the `intkey++` line.

A simple fix is to increment before you check for out of bounds. Also, I can't see why you exclude 0 from the list of hashes to check, so set the value back to 0 when it overflows.

```
while(hasharr[intkey].frequency != 0 && hasharr[intkey].word != charkey)
{
    intkey++;
    if(intkey > 4000) 
        intkey = 0;
}
```

Why this makes your code wrong - aside from the "Undefined Behavior" of writing outside the array boundaries, which could cause your code to do anything (it crashed on my system), if it did succeed in writing past the end of the array, it would add the word to the word count, but the word would then not be found properly in your hash.

Comment: Thank you very much good sir. I knew it was something in that function.. Brain stops functioning properly after 11 hours of coding and teaching math. Ha! You're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a [Hash Collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack), meaning two keys are producing the same has value. You may have to change the way you are computing your hash value or catch the instances where two keys are producing the same hash value by adding a hash collision function.

Have a look at [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/836212-hashing-collision-resolution).